# Defining a custom probability density function for Maximum likelihood in matlab

Tags: statistics, matlab, maximum-likelihood

I am trying to minimise a likelihood function and estimate the parameter value of $\lambda$ by fitting to the following data.  $t$ is the time and $N(t)$ si the population measured at those specific time points
$t=[0;1;2;3;4;5;6];$

$N(t)=[350000,210000,80000,20000,100,100,100];  $

The probability density function is $f_N(N(t);\lambda t)=\lambda t e^{-\lambda t N(t)}$.
The Cumulative distribution function is $1-e^{-\lambda tN(t)}$

This is the Matlab code I wrote:

```
N=[350000,200000,80000,20000,100,100,100];
t=[0 1 2 3 4 5 6];
cutOff=100;
c=(N<=cutOff);%censored data
start=1/mean(N);

pdf_lambda=@(N,lambda)lambda.*t.*exp(-lambda.*t.*N);
cdf_lambda=@(N,lambda)1-exp(-lambda.*t.*N);
[paramEsts,paramCIs] = mle(N, 'censoring',c,'pdf',pdf_lambda, 'cdf',cdf_lambda, ...
                           'start',start, 'lower',0);
```

I get an error as `Unable to perform assignment because the size of the left side is 1-by-1 and the size of the right side is
1-by-7.`

This is the first time I am using MLE to fit for data and estimate a parameter. So I don't quite understand what I ma dong wrong here. Can someone please let me know how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is due to the definition of the PDF you care about. Just basically check your function handle "pdf_lambda", one could find that the value of this function is actually a vector. However, for a PDF (or CDF) function used in "mle" must be a scalar value function.

This is interesting because the PDF function at different time $t$ is actually different and depends on the parameter $t$. Nevertheless, the PDF function that we estimate the parameter for should be the same in MLE scheme. It may suggest that it is not appropriate to use the data N to estimate.

My suggestion is to multiply the PDF function at different time $t$ together so that the PDF function can be treated as the scalar function of $\lambda$.

I haven't make it work through MATLAB yet, because the data you provide. Since $t=0$, the corresponding PDF function is $f_N(N(1);0)=0$, and the first entry of N should be considered if it is appropriate.

I here suppose that the first entry of $t$ and $N$ are not taken into consideration. The MATLAB code is as follow:

```
N=[200000,80000,20000,100,100,100];
t=[1 2 3 4 5 6];
cutOff=100;
c=(N<=cutOff);%censored data
start=1/mean(N);

pdf_lambda=@(N,lambda)prod(lambda.*[1 2 3 4 5 6].*exp(-lambda.*[1 2 3 4 5 6].*[200000,80000,20000,100,100,100]));
cdf_lambda=@(N,lambda)prod(1-exp(-lambda.*[1 2 3 4 5 6].*[200000,80000,20000,100,100,100]));
[paramEsts,paramCIs] = mle(N, 'censoring',c,'pdf',pdf_lambda, 'cdf',cdf_lambda, ...
                           'start',start, 'lower',0);
```

Note: Please do not use $t$ and $N$ in the function handle, because these parameters will not be transferred into the function "mle".

Comment: Can I know the reason behind taking the product? How was it decided it will solve the problem? Also, if $f_N(N(t);\lambda t)$ follows a Poisson distribution instead of an exponential distribution will it still be ok to use the product?

Comment: Also is there a way to provide $t$ and $N$ to the `pdf_lambda` function as I have to try this for various data sets

Comment: @sam_rox The reason I take the product is that you can treat $t$ as a parameter of the exponential distribution. I here assumed that the exp. distributions at different time $t$ are independent with each other. The multiplication is actually the joint distribution of the data you provide. If you want to change the distribution into the Poisson distribution you should also try to figure out the pdf for the MLE estimator, and I think the product still works. BTW, Since you haven't provided the background of your code, I think maybe you could check Poisson process to get a better understandings.

Comment: @sam_rox As for the question about $t$ and $N$, I think the "mle" is not flexible to deal with these two parameters.